# How to pivot values taken from 1 cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010, powerquery

How do I pivot CSV values in a cell in Excel (preferably Excel 2010) ?

Is it possible to do it without PowerQuery ?

**Example:**

Data:

```
Company     Rating      Reason
ABC         1           Professional,Ethical,Customer Service
STU         1           Customer Service,Professional
VWX         1           Professional
MNO         2           Reliable,Responsive
PQR         2           Reliable
DEF         3           Responsive
GHI         4           Value,Reputation
JKL         5           Competency,Professional,Quality
YZ          5           Competency
```

Desired pivot table:

```
                        Count
1
    Professional        3
    Customer Service    2
    Ethical             1
2
    Reliable            2
    Responsive          1
3
    Responsive          1
4
    Value               1
    Reputation          1
5
    Competency          2
    Professional        1
    Quality             1
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a non-powequery answer but tagged your question to powerquery. But if you decide to go the powerquery route, you could try

**If there were separate columns/rows:**

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Rating"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=List.Combine(List.Transform(_[Reason], each Text.Split(_,","))),
    b =  Table.FromList(a, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    c = Table.Group(b, {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    d=Table.Sort(c,{{"Count", Order.Descending}})
in d
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Column1", "Count"}, {"Column1", "Count"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

**If everything is in one single cell**

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
#"Split Column by Positions" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0,12, 24}), {"Company", "Rating","Reason"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Positions",{{"Company", type text}, {"Rating", type text}, {"Reason", type text}}),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type1",1),

#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Top Rows", {"Rating"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=List.Combine(List.Transform(_[Reason], each Text.Split(_,","))),
    b =  Table.FromList(a, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    c = Table.Group(b, {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    d=Table.Sort(c,{{"Count", Order.Descending}})
in d
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Column1", "Count"}, {"Column1", "Count"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]